# A grazing image - help finding a word

Tags: word-request

Recently I heard an interesting sentence on the radio but now I forgot it. It was used like this: that boy is a X image of his father. I thought it was "grazing" but when I looked on Google it was not correct. Can you help me find out what the sentence is? Thank you very much.

By the way, I found that Grazing means grassland suitable for pasturage or eat grass in a field. But that's not what I need. When I search up "the grazing image" I just got some photos of cows eating grass.

Comment: The phrase that occurs to me is [spitting image](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spitting%20image) although that doesn't sound anything like *grazing image*.

Comment: Just 'the image' of someone is also possible, or 'the very image', which doesn't sound like 'grazing'.

Comment: There's [**graven image,**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/graven-image) but that's *an idol—an object or image, such as a statue, that is worshipped as the representation of a deity or god.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly "That boy is the *[spitting image](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-the-spitting-image-of-sb)* of his father".

That doesn't sound much like "grazing", but this is a standard idiom meaning "look very similar"

Comment: You and stangdon are right. I'm just remembering the sentence wrong. Thanks, now I know what it is, a spitting image!

Comment: I think Americans use ***He's the spitting image** [of someone he looks just like]* at least as often as Brits. But ***He's the dead spit** [of doppleganger]* seems to be almost exclusively a Briticism.

Comment: The expression was originally __spit and image._ https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/spitting-image-origin-meaning

Answer (score 1):

The speaker probably said, "That boy is the **graven image** of his father." It's a common mistake: a mishmash of "spitting (or very) image of..." and "graven image of..." *Graven* is the past participle of the archaic verb [grave](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grave) (definition 3), meaning *engrave*.